# The fastest and most efficient way to get repeated numbers in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I know how to do this combining a lot of `if...else` statements but I need a faster and more efficient way.
I need a function that will run through a nested array and return the numbers that occur more than once in the nested array.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array/840808#840808) doesn't work with nested arrays and even if you use `flat()`, the code still breaks when the duplicates in the array are more than 2

For example-
Lets call the name of the function `deepSort(nestedArray)`
where `nestedArray` is the nested array parameter

```
deepSort([[1,3,4,5], [4,7,9,1,3], [2,3,5], [1,2,3,4]]) //Returns 1,2,3,4,5
```

```
deepSort([[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [2,9,0]]) //Returns 2
```

```
deepSort([[2,7,9], [4,3], [9,6,5], [1,4,3]]) //Returns 3,4,9
```

**What I tried**

```
function deepSort(nestedArray) {
  const flatArr = nestedArray.flat().sort();
  let results = []
  for (let i = 0; i < flatArr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (flatArr[i + 1] ==flatArr[i]) {
      results.push(flatArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return (results.filter((item,index) => results.indexOf(item) === index)).join()
}
```

Can this be optimized any more for speed and efficiency when handling larger values of data?

Comment: Step 1: [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/840808/519413

Comment: I don't want to debug it. I want an entirely new function. Created by someone here

Comment: That's not how this site works. We are here to help you to debug code, not to write it for you.

Comment: Oh, I would actually drop the one I did. Thanks for the Information.

Comment: As for the links you dropped, that gave me a very good idea. By flattening the array and looking for the duplicates. But the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/840808/519413) , the function there breaks with repeated values of more than 2.
Thank you for your efforts @RoryMcCrossan